# Append to Same file using fileoutput stream

Tags: java, file, io, fileoutputstream, poi-hssf

I am using multiple methods to get data to be written to an .xlsx file. I am using HSSF for this. The first method creates a fileOutputStream and subsequent methods append to that stream and that is written to the file. Something like:

```
FileFileOutputStream infoHeadersPart = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath+fileName),true);
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

private void firstMethod(String filePath, String fileName, HashMap<String, Object> generalInfo) {
//Some Stuff
workbook.write(infoHeadersPart);
}
private void secondMethod()
{
//Some Stuff
workbook.write(infoHeadersPart);
infoHeadersPart.close();      
}
```

When I open the file, it only reflects the data of firthMethod() written and does not write from secondMethod().

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That makes no sense. You can't just write an excel workbook to a file and than write a second one to the same file. An Excel file is supposed to contain a single workbook, not two.

Comment: What do you want to achieve when appending one `xlsx` to another? You know that xlsx is simple zip archive and when you appends one to another second is ignored by most of software?

Comment: @JBNizet So how do I append to a workbook then? I need all this data on one single workbook.

Comment: First you need to understand the structure. A workbook has several sheets, and each sheet contains data. If you start from scratch and want to generate an Excel file, the create a single workboow, generate all the sheets and data, then write it once to the file. If you already have an Excel file that you want to modify, then use POI to read that Excel file as a workbook, then update this workboow and write it when you're done.